# exclude metaclass properties for groovy model classes in swagger

Tags: groovy, jackson, swagger, swagger-ui

How do we exclude metaclass properties in model for "groovy" classes as Response? I have a Jax-Rs resource which returns a groovy object annotated with swagger @ApiModel.
I see too many groovy specific attributes in swagger ui. How do I exclude it from serialization?

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Document(collection = 'MongoCollection')
@CompileStatic
@ToString
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@ApiModel(value = "Represents a document from mongo collection")
class Foo {
..
..

}
```

It seems to be using Jackson for pogo-json serialization? How do annotate my groovy class to exclude metaclass properties from getting into json serialized string?
I tried using JsonIgnoreProperties annotation but it didnt help.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = ["MetaClass","MetaMethod"])
```

Comment: Have you tried with lower-case `metaClass` instead of `MetaClass`?

Comment: Yes. Did not help with lower case.

Comment: Maybe related? https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc/issues/163

Comment: I ensured am not using jackson-1 in any of my dependencies. classpath contains all jackon-2 jars. enabling debug shows that "com.wordnik.swagger.converter.ModelPropertyParser" class is not ignoring the metaClass property.

Comment: this looks like swagger issue. When I unit tested my Rest service, Json returned honoured JsonIgnoreProperties fields. They were "null" in the response. But the when the service documentation is viewed using swagger-ui, json representation for the same class is not ignoring the groovy metaClass fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a bug in swagger as per https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues/519.
I switched from groovy to java classes for model objects to proceed as of now. Will work on creating a test for this issue when I get time.

Answer (score 5):

If using springfox, see springfox [issues 752](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/752), found a way to resolve this :

```
docket.ignoredParameterTypes(groovy.lang.MetaClass.class)
```

A code example is:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {
     @Bean
     public Docket api() {
         return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
             .ignoredParameterTypes(groovy.lang.MetaClass.class)
             .select()
             .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
             .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
             .paths(PathSelectors.any())
             .build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

https://springdoc.org/#groovy-support

Including this dependency with the springdoc-openapi-ui dependency will resolve the issue in the newer versions.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-groovy</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.13</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading Swagger to a version >= 1.3.5 should resolve this.